# Installl .exe app to remote computers - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've been slamming my head against the wall with this one.

**EXPECTED**:

- I want this to simply grab a file from my \DC\ShareDrive - Copy it to the computer on C:\temp and run it

**WHAT IS ACTUALLY DOING**:

- The script is able to create the temp folder across all 3 computers but only runs it on DC01 which is where I am running the script from.

SERVERS.txt - **Contains** w/o spaces
USER01
DC01
EX01

```
$computers = Get-Content c:\software\servers.txt
$sourcefile = "\\dc01\software\install\AcrobatDC.exe"

foreach ($computer in $computers){
$destinationfolder = "\\$computer\C$\temp\"

if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationfolder -Credential $domaincredentials)) 
{ 
New-Item $destinationfolder -Type Directory -Credential 
$domaincredentials
    }
    }

    Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationfolder -Credential 
$domaincredentials

    Invoke-Command -cn $computer -Credential $domaincredentials -ScriptBlock 
{Powershell.exe C:\temp\AcrobatDC.exe /sAll /msi /norestart ALLUSERS=1 
EULA_ACCEPT=YES}
```

Comment: I does not give me any errors, but it only copies the executable to 1 computer and only the folder to the rest of them.

Comment: [Double hop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.1) issue. ?

Comment: **"The script is able to create the temp folder across all 3 computers
 but only runs it on DC01 which is where I am running the script from"**.  so acrobatdc.exe is not being copied ? just the folder being created ?

Comment: if yes, try to manually copy using this command **Copy-Item -Path '\\dc01\software\install\AcrobatDC.exe" -Destination '\\$computer\C$\temp\'**  just to see the command works, permissions ok etc

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem comes from bad indentation of the code. Because of that, it is hard to notice that you are performing the `Copy-Item` and `Invoke-Command` lines **outside** the foreach loop.

I didn't test the actual scriptblock for the adobe install, but I think you may also change that.

Try

```
$computers  = Get-Content -Path 'c:\software\servers.txt'
$sourcefile = "\\dc01\software\install\AcrobatDC.exe"

foreach ($computer in $computers){
    $destinationfolder = "\\$computer\C$\Temp"

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationfolder -Credential $domaincredentials)) { 
        New-Item $destinationfolder -Type Directory -Credential $domaincredentials
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationfolder -Credential $domaincredentials

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $domaincredentials -ScriptBlock { 
        & 'C:\temp\AcrobatDC.exe' "/sAll /msi /norestart ALLUSERS=1 EULA_ACCEPT=YES"
    }
}
```